# How to make a textarea take markdown properties (HTML)

Tags: html, reactjs, markdown, markup

How do I use markdown properties in a HTML text area, a little like stack overflow's body area?

Of course I have my standard text area made out like this:

```
<textarea className="form__input form__group"
    value={body}
    onChange={e => setBody(e.target.value)} />
```

But I would like to be able to use markup/markdown tags in my text area to then get an output for when the post is made.
for example:

```
# Hello there,
> I want to be able to make mytext area be able to take this and then output markdown style body.
```

## Hello there,

> I want to be able to make mytext area be able to take this and then output markdown style body.

Comment: Well there's plenty of existing markdown editor libraries for React, like this one: https://github.com/andrerpena/react-mde - is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: Right, @Jayce444 I tried the parser/editor you commented but i don't see anyway to obtain the html text output to send it to my database, Do you have any ideo on how to do so?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a library to assist with the markdown. I have used this one before and it works quite well: https://uiwjs.github.io/react-md-editor/

install: `npm i @uiw/react-md-editor`

Import into react: `import MEditor from "@uiw/react-md-editor";`

Then just use the MEditor and MEditor.markdown components to input and show your markdown.

There is way more info in the docs so just read https://uiwjs.github.io/react-md-editor/

Answer (score 2):

I also use [@uiw/react-md-editor](https://github.com/uiwjs/react-md-editor) as Croc suggested.
I would also recommend taking care of malicious scripts that untrusted bad actors/users may abuse.

Unfortunately, that's not well documented in the library documentation so here's how you may want to do it:

In edit mode:

```
<MDEditor
   value={value}
   autoFocus={false}
   onChange={handleChange}
   previewOptions={{ skipHtml: true, escapeHtml: true, transformLinkUri: null, linkTarget: '_blank' }}
/>
```

In preview/read-only mode:

```
<MDEditor.Markdown source={value} escapeHtml={true} skipHtml={true} transformLinkUri={null} />
```

Comment: This looks like what I need, but I can't find anything in the docs for escapeHtml or transformLinkUri.  Where do I look?

Answer (score 0):

I use [react-markdown-editor-lite](https://harrychen0506.github.io/react-markdown-editor-lite/) in most of my projects.

```
// import react, react-markdown-editor-lite, and a markdown parser you like
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import MarkdownIt from 'markdown-it'
import MdEditor from 'react-markdown-editor-lite'
// import style manually
import 'react-markdown-editor-lite/lib/index.css';

// Register plugins if required
// MdEditor.use(YOUR_PLUGINS_HERE);

// Initialize a markdown parser
const mdParser = new MarkdownIt(/* Markdown-it options */);

// Finish!
function handleEditorChange({html, text}) {    
  console.log('handleEditorChange', html, text)
  //You can use the text props to save it to your database
}
export default (props) => {
  return (
    <MdEditor
      style={{ height: "500px" }}
      renderHTML={(text) => mdParser.render(text)}
      onChange={handleEditorChange}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try this code, To How to make a textarea take markdown properties (HTML).

```
<form>
    <input name="title" type="text" placeholder="Title?" />
    <textarea name="content" data-provide="markdown" rows="10"></textarea>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input name="publish" type="checkbox"> Publish
    </label>
    <hr/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

I hope this code will be useful to you.

Thank you.