# Textarea with markdown in React

Tags: reactjs, markdown, textarea

I'm creating a chat, and the text editor looks something like this

```js
<textarea
   {...registerForm("message", {
     required: true,
     maxLength: 400,
   })}
   value={message}
   placeholder="What's on your mind?"
   // ----
   onChange={onTextAreaChange}
   onSelect={onSelect}
   onFocus={() => {
     setIsMsgFocused(true);
   }}
   onBlur={() => {
     onBlur(500);
   }}
   // ----
   onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
   onKeyUp={onKeyUp}
   // ----
   onMouseDown={onMouseDown}
   // ----
   onInput={changeHeight}
/>
```

As you can see, it is difficult for me to change the textarea for something else and I wanted to know if there is a way for the textarea to show me the markdown within it.

Does anyone know if there is a way to achieve this or what they recommend I do? This problem is for a chat that I am creating similar to Discord.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a textarea take markdown properties (HTML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65557500/how-to-make-a-textarea-take-markdown-properties-html)